# Rock, Paper, Scissors on Python - Can't get computer to play?

Tags: python

[image: Here is the assignment:]

```
# This program will generate a random game of Rock, Paper, Scissors
# in which the player will be able to win/lose against the computer

import sys
import random

print("*********************************")
print("Let't Play Rock, Paper, Scissors!")
print("*********************************")

def computer():
        number = random.randint (0,2)
        if (computer == 0):
                computer = "Rock";
        elif (computer == 1):
                       computer = "Paper";
        elif (computer == 2):
                       computer = "Scissors";
# need to repeat seven times



player = input("Enter 0 for Rock, 1 for Paper, 2 for Scissors: ")

#determine winner
if (player == computer):
        print("It's a draw. Nobody won that round.")

elif (player == "Rock"):
        if (computer == "Paper"):
            print("Paper covers rock! Computer wins this round.")

elif (player == "Paper"):
        if (computer == "Rock"):
            print("Paper covers rock! You win this round.")

elif (player == "Rock"):
        if (computer == "Scissors"):
            print("Rock busts scissors! You win this round.")
elif (player == "Scissors"):
        if (computer == "Rock"):
            print("Rock busts scissors! Computer wins this round.")

elif (player == "Scissors"):
        if (computer == "Paper"):
            print("Scissors cut paper! You win this round.")
elif (player == "Paper"):
        if (computer == "Scissors"):
            print("Scissors cut paper! You win this round.")


#show_winner
```

It seems like I can't get the computer to play or to show the result such as "paper covers rock," etc...
Any help would be appreciated...
This is what the module results in:[image]

Comment: This is a question of implementation, not design (please read the [help/on-topic] to see what is appropriate for Programmers.SE).

Comment: You're not calling your function `computer`, but comparing it to a string.

Comment: You're not calling the function, you're just comparing the function's *name*. E.g., try `print(computer)` versus `print(computer())`. Besides that, your `computer()` function is not returning any result (which implicitly then returns `None`).

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of issues with your `computer` function, and how you're calling it.

Firstly, it needs to return the value it's chosen, not assign it to it's own name:

```
def computer():
    number = random.randint (0,2)
    if (computer == 0):
       return "Rock";
    elif (computer == 1):
       return "Paper";
    elif (computer == 2):
       return "Scissors";
```

And when you do your comparisons, you actually need to call the function `computer()`, not just compare to it's name:

```
if (player == computer()):
```

Notice the `()` after computer?

Finally, to actually play 7 times, you need to wrap the whole question/answer logic in some kind of loop:

```
for attempt in range(7):
    player = input("Enter 0 for Rock, 1 for Paper, 2 for Scissors: ")
    ...
```

You also seem to be accepting an integer from the player (`0`, `1`, or `2`), but your computer function is returning `Rock`, `Paper`, or `Scissors`. You need to choose one or the other.